# Trying to make my work easier by finding and matching values on

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

So I'm trying to figure out how to make Excel to find and match values, show which do match and which do not.

So in column A have a value and match it to column B. If they match then show them in green. Then show values that did not match from A in C and from B in D. Something like this.

[image: Example]

Please note that even tho Banana is not in same row, it shows that they match.

Comment: Shouldn't `"Banana"` (correctly spelled) **fail to match** `"Bannana"` (incorrectly spelled)?  If that's not the only reason your code isn't working, please paste the code into the question so that we can help you get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use some simple excel formulas in order to do something close to this.

You would need in the correct order one inside the other:

- IF(condition;value_if_true;value_if_false)
- ISNUMBER(expression)
- MATCH(lookup_value;lookup_array;match_type)

(Look them up for further info)

Also for the "coloring" you need some conditional formatting with a formula. Also look that up ([Conditional Formatting with Formula Tutorial](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f)).

For the formula you can do:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2;B$2:B$4;0));"";A2)
```

The result will be something like that:

[image]

To show you what I did exactly I removed the "=" from the formulas on the first rows. That's how it actually looks in your table:

[image]

If you extend the formulas on the other rows you get the result in the first picture. The result would have multiple empty rows (Those that match) but you will have the desired result in general. You can then sort the columns or remove the blanks if you want.

For the conditional formatting do something like that:

[image: Conditional Formatting those that Match]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I really appreciate it. I've been implementing everything and it works pretty well.

Have a one question tho. Is there a way to sort a column do there are no blank spaces? So in column C there are 2 blank spaces before Watermelon comes up and i would like to move it to top.

I hope my ramblings make sense.

Comment: First of all, and because you are new in SO, if the answer helped you and answers correctly your question please accept (huge tick left side of the answer) and if you want upvote it so others in the future can easily spot the correct answer (it really helps keeping things organised).

Comment: Now I understand what you want to do but you cannot do that with the formulas (they recalculate each time you move them in another cell) and you cannot sort their results. You have to "copy and paste special as values" the results and then sort without expanding the selection.

Comment: One last question. On cells without values there is 0 instead of being blank. I've tried IFERROR and IFNA but i cannot get it to work. My code looks like this.


`=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2;B$2:B$100;0));"";A2)`

Comment: The formula is correct. I don't know why it gives 0 instead of "empty string". My best guess is, that it has something to do with the cell format you have choosen. Check if it is "General"...